# Could someone help identify this component?

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount

I am trying to identify this component, I need to replace it. It is in a Belkin SoundForm Elite that keeps rebooting.

The plug-in charger is 19V.

The component is the eight-legged one marked 0U=V2P (removed in second picture).

[image]

[image]

Comment: If is _is_ a microcontroller, replacing it won't do you any good because it won't be programmed.

Comment: It looks more like a switching regulator of some kind.  Probably has a 3.3V output.

Comment: Considering L301 and C328, it could very well be a switching regulator.

Comment: Hello and welcome ... do you have a picture of more of the board please_

Answer (score 9):

That's no microcontroller. Based on things surrounding it, it's a buck regulator.

In fact, it's a Richtek RT6217A.

[Product page](https://www.richtek.com/Home/Products/Switching%20Regulators/DC_DC%20StepDown%20Convertor/RT6217ART6217B?ForceDevice=1&devicename=richtekweb&sc_lang=en)

[Datasheet](https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT6217A=RT6217B/DS6217AB-01.pdf) confirms that RT6217AHGJ8F in TSOT-23-8 package has product code "0U=", and the pinout matches too. In addition to the triangular mark for pin 1.

Also, if you think replacing the regulator fixes it, it might not if the problem is elsewhere and regulator is either controlled incorrectly or it shuts down due to overcurrent protection. So don't replace it unless you know it is broken, most likely it isn't if you are just guessing instead of doing proper fault analysis.

Comment: Which can be replaced...

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Sure, it can be replaced. But replacing it won't help if the regulator is fine. The problem may be elsewhere, and it might make the regulator periodically shut down and start again.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to revise the comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment! I did check everything, and the regulator is broken.

Comment: @TomekSikorski I would be interested to know the method you used to determine it is broken, if you thought it was a microcontroller instead of buck regulator. Sort of like when a fuse blows, and instead of determining why it blew up and removing the faulty circuit, people simply change a new fuse which again blows immediately.

Comment: Yes, considering a misidentification of the component the statement "it is broken" is rather suspicious